# NavigationError on NavigateTo

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I'm trying out Blazor ServerSide and created a Component to Redirect To the Login Page when a user is not logged in.

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationManager NavigationManager;

@code {
/// <inheritdoc />
protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Login");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

}

But always when "NavigateTo" is called the following exception is thrown:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationException' was thrown.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteNavigationManager.NavigateToCore(String uri, Boolean forceLoad)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationManager.NavigateTo(String uri, Boolean forceLoad)
   at ApplySupportTool.Blazor.Pages.RedirectToLogin.OnInitializedAsync() in C:\\Users\\padruttn\\Documents\\git\\ApplySupportTool\\src\\ApplySupportTool.Blazor\\Pages\\RedirectToLogin.razor:line 8"
```

Interesstingly the navigation is made despite the exception.
I also tried to call it with the path "/login" but the same behaviour here.

Comment: That's got to be one of the worst (least descriptive) exceptions I've ever seen. GG Microsoft.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13582#issuecomment-527383363

Comment: If someone is looking for a complete answer, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74721678/8644294

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is an [open issue on github](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13582) for this problem. See also the [preceeding issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/11591) where a possible workaround is mentioned: putting the `NavigateTo` method into `OnAfterRender` instead of `OnInitialized`.

Comment: The issue is no longer open and still remains unfixed, but moving the call to `OnAfterRender` works a charm!

Answer (score 16):

I needed to put this into `OnInitialized` rather than `OnAfterRender`, so had to go with the `render-mode="Server"` method, though apparently this isn't recommended.

It also states in the GitHub issue that this only happens in debug, not release, so a middle ground option is to change `_Host.cshtml` to contain:

```
<environment include="Staging,Production">
    <component render-mode="ServerPrerendered" type="typeof(App)" />
</environment>
<environment include="Development">
    <component render-mode="Server" type="typeof(App)" />
</environment>
```

Comment: I think this is the preferred solution until it is fixed!

Comment: I think that a better solution to this is to set a flag in your code behind, and then perform the navigation where you are expected to, after the rendering is complete.  You can use that same flag to optimize the rendering in the scenario.

Answer (score 15):

*Note that the following may be considered a workaround:*

You may also change your method to the following including the "async" keyword to its signature, there is going to be a complaint about not using await, but in exchange you are not going to need a return value. Since it doesn't have an 'await' the effect is kinda the same as the synchronous version, but without the exception being thrown.

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Login");
}
```

Here is an example where i am using a RedirectToLogin.razor component in my routing

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

@code{

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var returnUrl = "~/" + NavigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(NavigationManager.Uri);
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"Identity/Account/Login?returnUrl={returnUrl}", forceLoad:false);
    }

}
```

And in my App.razor

```
 <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <RedirectToLogin />
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
 </Found>
```

Comment: Can you explain `"~/"`? This does not work for me locally and I end up with https://localhost:1234/~/ which is not found.

Answer (score 12):

use OnInitializedAsync replace OnInitialized

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    nav.NavigateTo("/login", true);
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution

Answer (score 10):

I ran into the same problem and filed [issue #28355](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28355). The official answer is, that it is save to ignore the exception when `NaviagteTo` is placed in `OnInitialized`. Here is the answer from javiercn:

> Yes, it is completely safe to ignore it. The debugger stops because it is configured to do so, but in this case the exception is always handled. You can turn-off breaking on this exception if it's caught on the debugger settings.

[Issue #13582](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13582) deals with how to prevent the debugger from stopping at this exception.

Answer (score 9):

Old post, but - if you are running a Blazor Server app, this behavior only happens if render-mode is "ServerPrerendered".  Disabling Pre-rendering by changing the mode to "Server" makes the exception not be thrown in the first place:

```
<app>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />
</app>
```

I've searched current Blazor Documentation and change notes, and haven't found any mention of this, so just in case it helps somebody else...

Comment: It works, but its a "sledge-hammer for a nail" fix :-s

Answer (score 2):

I had this when I tried to call the navigateto from another thread. render-mode = "Server" - solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

This issue persists on .Net 8,

In my case, I only encounter it whenever my **debugger** is on. The current solution is to put your `NavigationManager` code in `try-catch` and simply ignore it.

.Net team planned to fix it in .Net 9.
You can track the issue on [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/53996).

Answer (score -1):

In .NET 5.0, in the _host.cshtml file. Past the following @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync(RenderMode.Server)) in the line after the "blazor_error_ui" section.

Comment: On Net5.0 I get an error: "Error CS0411 The type arguments for method 'HtmlHelperComponentExtensions.RenderComponentAsync<TComponent>(IHtmlHelper, RenderMode)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Answer (score -1):

A simple workaround that i used is to encapsulate the navigation code in a try catch block

```
                @try
                {
                    if (context != null)
                    {
                        if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                        {
                            var returnUrl = _navigation.ToBaseRelativePath(_navigation.Uri);
                            returnUrl = "~/" + returnUrl;
                            _navigation.NavigateTo($"Identity/Account/Login?returnUrl={returnUrl}", forceLoad: true);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                }
```