# Blazor redirect to login if user is not authenticated

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I am trying to develop an app using Blazor WebAssembly and I am wondering about how I can protect my whole application if the user is not authenticated. The behavior I would implement is:

- *If an anonymous user asks for any page, then he will be redirected to the login page*

Better

- *a user **must** be authenticated for using this app*

At the moment I've implemented this behavior applying the `[Authorize]` attribute to every page, but I would like to centralize it.

I've achieved this goal on Blazor Server Side applying the `[Authorize]` attribute inside the `_host.razor` component.

Is there a solution even for Blazor Client Side?

Comment: If someone is looking for a complete answer, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74721678/8644294

Answer (score 62):

There may be slicker ways of doing this, but this is what worked for me:

Assuming you've configured Authentication correctly according to [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

In your MainLayout.razor (which is used by default for all components) add a `code` block as follows:

```cs
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@code{ 

    [CascadingParameter] protected Task<AuthenticationState> AuthStat { get; set; }

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        var user = (await AuthStat).User;
        if(!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"authentication/login?returnUrl={Uri.EscapeDataString(NavigationManager.Uri)}");
        }
    }
}
```

If the user is not authenticated, we redirect to the built-in The RemoteAuthenticatorView component at the "authentication/" enpoint with the "login" action. This should kick-off authentication

Comment: You need to `@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager`, otherwise `CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'NavigationManager.Uri'`.

Comment: Another thing, `NavigationManager.Uri` returns fully qualified URL, but if AspNet Identity is used as Authentication Provider, it will intend to redirect you to a local Url using `LocalRedirect(returnUrl);`. So it wants a local URL that can be obtained with `NavigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(NavigationManager.Uri)`.

Comment: Thanks @Arsinclair - your tweaks made this work for me. I wrapped it up in a component and it works a treat. https://github.com/Webreaper/Damselfly/blob/develop/Damselfly.Web/Shared/LoginForcer.razor

Answer (score 37):

Basically to apply authorization to all pages in BlazorApp.Client, you have to add:

```
@attribute [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Authorize]
```

...to your _Imports.razor file.

Furthermore, you can add:

```
@attribute [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AllowAnonymous]
```

...on pages that don't require authorization.

Also if you wanted to redirect a user to any page, here is something I came up with:

```
<NotAuthorized>
    @{ navMan.NavigateTo("login"); }
</NotAuthorized>
```

...where navMan is an injected instance of NavigationManager. Here i'm redirecting the user to my Login.razor if they try to access an authorized user only page .

Comment: is the `<NotAuthorized>` hack still the best thing blazor wasm has to offer to redirect to the login page?

Comment: The condition is redundant. Just use:
`<NotAuthorized>@{ _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/login"); }</NotAuthorized>`

Comment: @ssamko Yes, this is a better statement.

Comment: @mend0k can you edit your original post to include ssamko's suggestion?  Also can you specify where the <NotAuthorized> block goes (because it does not go in _Imports.razor).

Answer (score 16):

I tried the solution from @Brett and it worked but on redirect back to the page the user came from it ended up saying `Authorizing...`, `Checking login state...` and then finally  `Completing login...` and got stuck there. The user then had to click on a link or manually type the previous URL to get back.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Microsoft now has documentation for "**Require authorization for the entire app**".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#require-authorization-for-the-entire-app

According to the documentation you can either:

- Use the Authorize attribute directive in the `_Imports.razor` file:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@attribute [Authorize]
```

- Add the Authorize  attribute to each Razor component in the Pages folder.

I added the code to `_Imports.razor` but then I only received a white screen for content:

[image]

I then noticed that `https://localhost:44123/authentication/login` also gave me a white screen that `Shared\RedirectToLogin.razor` normally points to. I then added `@attribute [AllowAnonymous]` to `Pages\Authentication.razor` and then everything worked as expected and I did not get stuck.

[image]

With this solution I could also see the default `You are logged out.` message.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me figure this out.

Answer (score 10):

You can create your own redirecting component `LoginRedirect.razor`.

```
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]
@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/login");
    }
}
```

and then just use it in the `App.razor` like this:

```
<NotAuthorized>
    <LoginRedirect />
</NotAuthorized>
```

and dont forget to add `using` to that component based on your project structure on the top of the `App.razor` like:

```
@using SolutionName.ProjectName.Pages.MyFolder;
```

---

**EDIT:**

Seems like you don't have to create redirection component but you can use the page directly like:

```
<NotAuthorized>
    <LoginPage />
</NotAuthorized>
```

Comment: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationException` gets thrown on `_navigationManager.NavigateTo("/login");`

Comment: @iggy12345 Then try to put it to `OnAfterRender()` instead of `OnInitialized()`

Answer (score 4):

If your Blazor WASM is hosted inside .net .Server project (you have 3 projects in the solution: .Client, .Server and .Shared), add **.RequireAuthorization** to:

.Server/Program.cs (not the one in the .Client project)

```
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html").RequireAuthorization(); 
// redirect to login page BEFORE loading Blazor WASM page if auth is missing,
// use when ALL Blazor pages require autentication
// and you don't handle login screens etc. in Blazor but in the backend
```

**Or** you can wrap your  in app.razor in  and add custom LoginRedirect component suggested by @ssamko but make sure you use forceful redirection if the authentication URL is handled by .Server app.

app.razor:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using YourBlazor.Client.Components

<CascadingAuthenticationState>
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        Current user: @context.User.Identity.Name
            <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
                <Found Context="routeData">
                    <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
                    <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
                </Found>
                <NotFound>
                    <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
                    <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                        <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
                    </LayoutView>
                </NotFound>
            </Router>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <LoginRedirect />
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

Components/LoginRedirect.razor (note the **forceLoad:true**);

```
@using System.Web
@attribute [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AllowAnonymous]
@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/authentication/login?returnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_navigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(_navigationManager.Uri)), forceLoad:true);
        // /authentication controller is handled by hosted .Server project 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my trip to get familiar with Blazor, I am following a tutorial and the author has a nice and clean way to solve this problem as well. As everything seems to be a component in Blazor, your login page probably is a component as well. It is at least in the tutorial. So all he does is this:

```
<NotAuthorized>
    <Login />
</NotAuthorized>
```

And you need to add the correct using to your login component of course.

The downside to this solution is that the url doesn't match the page you see when you aren't logged in.

Answer (score 2):

You could leverage the `<NotAuthorizedContent>` template of the `<Router>` component as [described here](https://gist.github.com/SteveSandersonMS/175a08dcdccb384a52ba760122cd2eda#customizing-the-display-for-unauthenticated-users):

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="typeof(Startup).Assembly">
        <NotFoundContent>
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </NotFoundContent>
        <NotAuthorizedContent>
            <h1>Sorry</h1>
            <p>You're not authorized to reach this page. You may need to log in as a different user.</p>
        </NotAuthorizedContent>
        <AuthorizingContent>
            <p>Please wait...</p>
        </AuthorizingContent>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Replace the contents of `<NotAuthorizedContent>` with a custom component called something like `RedirectToLogin` whose `OnInitializedAsync` checks if the user is logged in, and if not, does the redirect.

Comment: "Now draw the rest of the owl"

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following lines to the client ..pages/Index.razor file.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@attribute [Authorize]
```

This will require the Index page to be authorized on start and force the login redirect as per RedirectToLogin component used in App.Razor.

Answer (score 1):

**Using the asp.net core identity login Page directly**

The folloing solution may not hit all whishes. Here you need to make your own razor component for your login. Instead of using the identity Page from asp.net core.

```
<NotAuthorized>
    <Login />
</NotAuthorized>
```

Better is to use the one from asp.net core. The problem here is, that you get an exception if you're not checking the NavigationManager. Here is the solution without exception.

```
<NotAuthorized>
    @{
        try
        {
            var hasJSRuntime = navManager != null && (navManager.GetType()?.GetProperty("HasAttachedJSRuntime") != null ? 
                (bool)navManager.GetType().GetProperty("HasAttachedJSRuntime").GetValue(navManager) : true);
        
            if (hasJSRuntime)
            {
                navManager.NavigateTo("/Identity/Account/Login", true);
            }

        }
        catch
        {
                <NavLink href="Identity/Account/Login">
                    Redirect to Login
                </NavLink>
        }
    }
</NotAuthorized>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Blazor server, this works using javascript interop:

Add js to _Layout.cshtml:

```
    window.forwardToLoginPage = () =>{
        window.location = "MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn"
    };
```

Create a component called ForwardToLogin

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS

@code {

  protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync()
  {
      await ForwardToLoginPage();
  }

  private async Task ForwardToLoginPage()
  {
      await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("forwardToLoginPage");
  }
}
```

Update App.razor:

```
 <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" >
       <NotAuthorized>
             <ForwardToLogin /> 
         </NotAuthorized>    
 </AuthorizeRouteView>
```

So now any time an unauthorzed uses tries to access a page with the [Authorize] attribute, he will be automatically forwarded to the login page. Note that the user is not redirected back to the original page though.

Comment: It's not working for me.  I get: InvalidOperationException: JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the component is being statically rendered. When prerendering is enabled, JavaScript interop calls can only be performed during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method. - call from await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("forwardToLoginPage");

Comment: @JClarkCDS, I updated the sample to use ` OnAfterRenderAsync()` which should resolve the issue you had.

Answer (score 0):

For Blazor Server, there seems to be no way to use the NavigationManager to navigate to an external link short of using JSInterop.

The reason for this is that the NavigationManager works only internally to the app.  If you give it an external url, it will generate a not found message.

You can do the following to customize the "Unauthorized" message.  Below, I have created a "NotAuthorized" component.

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" >
                <NotAuthorized>
                   <NotAuthorized />
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
        
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

NotAuthorized.razor

```
<h3>Not Authorized</h3>

Sorry, you are not authorized to access this page.

Please try logging in: <LoginDisplay />
```

The LoginDisplay shows the Login/Register buttons.