# How to require authentication for all by default in Blazor Server .Net 6 (with automatic login Page redirect)

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

I have tried this which was made for above .Net 3 but it is not working:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();        
});
```

Sorry i should also mention that if a user is not authenticated, i want to automatically redirect to the Login page.

the `@attribute [Authorize]` will only block access by saying "Not authorized" but i want users to be redirected to the Login page

after adding the `@attribute [Authorize]` in the _Imports.razor file this is what's showing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMHHa.png)

Comment: Blazor Server still runs on the server. If you disable anonymous logins on your server all calls will have to be authorized. In IIS, disabling anonymous logins and enabling Windows Authentication gives you automatic login using the user's account

Comment: The redirect could be a separate question but first look at this https://stackoverflow.com/q/60840986/60761

Comment: @Still, I've updated my answer to demonstrate how to automatically display the Login page when the user attempts to access a page protected by the Authorize attribute. See the UPDATE section in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that will work... Place the following code snippet in the _Imports.razor file

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@attribute [Authorize]
```

In that case, when the Index page is hit, the user will be redirected to the Login page. If you want to perform authentication before the Blazor App is being render, add the code snippet from above in the _Host.cshtml file

Add the `@attribute [AllowAnonymous]` to specific pages you want to exculde from authentication, as for instance, the Index page.

UPDATE: The following describes how to force automatic display of the Login page if the user is not authenticated:

Extend the `AuthorizeRouteView` component, residing in the App component like this:

```
<AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" 
                          DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
     <NotAuthorized>
         @{
           NavigationManager.NavigateTo("identity/account/login", 
             forceLoad: true);
           }
      </NotAuthorized>
      <Authorizing>
           Wait...
      </Authorizing>
</AuthorizeRouteView>
```

The code above navigates the user to the Login page if he's not authorized to view the page. Warning a user may be authenticated and still not authorized to view a specific page. You're code should verify if the user is authenticated, and if he does, let him know that he's not authorized to view the current page. If he's not authenticated, send him to the Login page. Note that basic authorization only requires that the user is authenticated.

Here's the complete code for the App.razor component:

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" 
                          DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
     <NotAuthorized>
         @{
           NavigationManager.NavigateTo("identity/account/login", 
             forceLoad: true);
           }
      </NotAuthorized>
      <Authorizing>
           Wait...
      </Authorizing>
</AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Comment: Or, disable anonymous login on the server itself, eg on IIS, and enable another authentication method

Comment: @enet Thank you for your updated answer, and i have used the approach you used on the `App.razor` file but use the ` <RedirectToLogin />` tag instead and now it seam to be working fine and the `RedirectToLogin.razor` page also changed slightly like this: `protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            var returnUrl = "~/" + Navigation.ToBaseRelativePath(Navigation.Uri);
            Navigation.NavigateTo($"Identity/Account/Login?returnUrl={returnUrl}", forceLoad:true);
        }` so i will accept your answer as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `@attribute [Authorize]` in _Import.razor file.

At this point, if you need some page without login, add `@attribute [AllowAnonymous]`