# Redirecting Users to login page when not logged in in blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to modify the stock blazor server project that gets created with visual studio so that it redirects the user to the login screen if they're not logged in.

The documentation on MSDN hasn't been clear so far as for how to do that and I managed to find a SO post [Blazor redirect to login if user is not authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60840986/blazor-redirect-to-login-if-user-is-not-authenticated) that seemed like it may be helpful, but is focused on web assembly, and not blazor server.

How do I redirect a person to the login screen automatically in blazor server?

I'm currently using the following:

1. I created a blazor server app in VS 2022, then created a scaffolded item for the login screen, assigning the `ApplicationDbContext.cs` as the context controller.
2. I Added `@attribute [Authorize]` to `_imports.razor` and `@attribute [AllowAnonymous]` to `Login.cshtml`
3. According to [Blazor redirect to login if user is not authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60840986/blazor-redirect-to-login-if-user-is-not-authenticated) I created a `LoginRedirect.razor` page that contains the following:

```
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]
@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/Identity/Account/Login");
    }
}
```

4. Then I set up my `App.razor` as follows:

```
@using LoginScaffolding.Pages
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication

<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
            <NotAuthorized>
                <LoginRedirect />
            </NotAuthorized>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

When I run this project I get a navigation exception, and I can't seem to fix it.

Comment: `LoginRedirect` isn't a page.  It's a component.  You can create the component in any folder.  Does `App.Razor` recognize that `<LoginRedirect />` exists?  If it does, then you probably have not yet scaffolded the Login page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked with one of the answers to the post I linked in my question above and managed to get the redirect to work by using `OnAfterRender` instead of `OnInitialized` in the redirect page.

This is the new `LoginRedirect.razor`

```cs
@using System.Security.Claims
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider
@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager;

@code {
    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
        _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/login", false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()` method to get the authentication state of the current user.

Try this code:

```
@using System.Security.Claims
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider
@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager;

@code {  
  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
     var authState = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
     var user = authState.User;
     if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
     {
         _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/Identity/Account/Login", false);
     }
  }
}
```

In the above code, `AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()` gets the authentication state of the current user. Then it redirects the user if his/her authentication state is not authenticated.

Comment: this doesn't work because `The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration or in script code BlazorConversionProject`

Comment: And if I put it in the method call, and switch the method to `async` it still doesn't work, I get the same navigation error

Comment: Dear @iggy12345 , I update my answer. it works. In my update, I use `OnInitializedAsync()` method. and variables are inside the method.