# (Blazor) NavigationManager is null?

Tags: c#, blazor, nullreferenceexception

Attempting to get visitors that aren't logged in to be redirected to the login page. This is my `Index.razor` file:

```cs
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
@code {
    public Index() {
        if (Auth.isLoggedIn() == false)
        {
            NavManager.NavigateTo("/login");
        }
    }
}
```

This results in an

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at PolAcaDossier.Pages.Index..ctor() in F:\dev\polacadossier\Pages\Index.razor:line 7
```

It seems to be working fine in another page. The implementation of that page is as follows:

```cs
@page "/account"
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

<br /><button class="btn-primary mt-3" @onclick="logOut">Uitloggen</button>

@code {
    private void logOut() {
        if (!Auth.isLoggedIn()) return;
        Auth.logout();
        NavManager.NavigateTo("/login");
    }
}
```

I have tried googling to see if anyone else had the same issue, I've asked the question on a programming Discord server and I've tried implementing it on a new page. All without success.

Comment: Try doing the same in `OnInitialized` not the CTOR. This is why it works on the second example.

Comment: Perhaps it's because you're using it in the constructor? I'm not familiar with how everything works in blazor, but I assume Blazor does the injection there. It sounds to me like you're trying to redirect in a suboptimal way. Is there no way you could add something in your router configuration or some intercepting logic that could control whether the path could be navigated to? Otherwise, you'd probably want to do something suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60840986

Comment: When you logout where are you going to land?? The login page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Blazor components, dependency injection is done by the Renderer and takes place after the Renderer instantiates an instance of the component i.e. after any Ctor has run. You should not try to access any injected object until `Attach` is called on the instance by the Renderer. As you are unlikely to be using `Attach` or `SetParametersAsync` in any `ComponentBase` component, consider the first method where you can call injected properties as `OnInitialized`.

In the code you've provided above, the first block attempts to access the property prior to injection.  In the second block you are accessing the property in a UI event which will be after the first render.

Answer (score 0):

Overlooking the obvious. You want to make the Index page force a login.

All you need to do is:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
@page "/"
@attribute [Authorize]
```

Try it!