# Redirecting from RedirectToLogin.razor gives error

Tags: redirect, blazor, blazor-server-side, identity

I have the following code:

**App.razor**

```
@using DorpshuisManager.Areas.Identity.Components

<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <RedirectToLogin ReturnUrl="@NavigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(NavigationManager.Uri)" />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p role="alert">Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page.</p>
                    }
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <div class="d-flex vw-100 vh-100 align-items-center justify-content-center text-center">
                    <div>

                        <iconify-icon icon="tabler:face-id-error" style="color: black;" width="100" height="100"></iconify-icon>
                        <h1>Pagina niet gevonden ...</h1>
                        <a href="/">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3 btn-rounded py-3 px-4">Ga naar home pagina</button>
                        </a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

**RedirectToLogin.razor**

```
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        ReturnUrl = "~/" + ReturnUrl;
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Identity/Account/Login?returnUrl=" + ReturnUrl, true);
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

[image: error preview]

I searched on Google and Stack Overflow, but all given anwsers are not working...

**I also tried [aspnetcore blazor navigation from razor component to razor page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60103674/aspnetcore-blazor-navigation-from-razor-component-to-razor-page/74721678#74721678) but this also didn't work**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NavigationError on NavigateTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58076758/navigationerror-on-navigateto)

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine I edited my question. Your suggestion and another post answer both didn't work...

Comment: The code from the listing does not match the code in the screenshot. If you trap the error do you get any more helpful information on the actual error that is occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Redirect component:

```
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

@if(IsAuthenticated)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page.</div>
}
else
{
    <div class="alert alert-info">Redirecting to the Log In Page.</div>
}


@code {
    [Parameter] public bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string ReturnUrl { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        // added to show the messsge
        await Task.Delay(2000);

        ReturnUrl = "/" + ReturnUrl;
        if (!IsAuthenticated)
            this.NavManager.NavigateTo("Identity/Account/Login?returnUrl=" + ReturnUrl, true);
    }
}
```

And `App`:

```cs
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <ReturnToLogin IsAuthenticated="context.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false" />
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
```