# NavigationException: "Exception_WasThrown" in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I try to navigate to another page with but I get every time the exeption: "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationException: Exception_WasThrown". Do you now what I need to do or what is wrong here?

[image]

on my dashboard page I have @page "/dashboard", so I dont think the string is wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58076758/navigationerror-on-navigateto ?

Comment: If the above answer doesn't fit, show some more code.  There's no context in a single line of code!

Comment: Are you able to run it in Visual Studio's debug mode? Might provide some more info. Also, does `/dashboard` load when you go to the page directly?

Comment: Hi @XDboy, any update? Did my answer help you resolve your issue?

Comment: I already fixes it in another page with a button which has a href to my dashboard. I didnt try your code @Rena but I think to navigate with OnInitalized should work. Thanks for the answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you add this code in `@code{}`? If not, it will get such exception but if you still `F5` to continue the debug, it will then render the redirect page. This is a first chance exception that is thrown to cause a redirect to happen during pre-rendering. A workaround is to turn off first-chance exceptions you won't see this happen, you could check [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14464#issuecomment-540512447).

```
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
    
<p>Redirecting to Page</p>
@if (condition) {
    NavManager.NavigateTo($"/dashboard");   
}
```

Another workaround is that you could put these code to `@code{}`:

```
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager NavManager        
<p>Redirecting to Page</p>    
@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        @if (condition) {
            NavManager.NavigateTo($"/dashboard");  
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a navigation expert, but I think maybe you need to get the base:

`LoginNavigator.NavigateTo(LoginNavigator.BaseUri + $"/dashboard", true);`

Comment: This isn't required -  `NavManager.NavigateTo("/fetchdata");` works just fine.

Comment: ty for info, Shaun.  I needed it, but I think it's because my Blazor project is a sub-app of my main site.  But I doubt that has anything to do with the OP question.